# How to set up PHP script to receive requests to non-existent directories in a directory?

Tags: php, linux, dreamhost

Say, if I have a `dir` directory in a root directory on the server with `index.php` file in it, can I set up that `index.php` to be called for any of the following links:

```
https://example.com/dir/
https://example.com/dir/something
https://example.com/dir/something_else
```

Sorry, I'm not sure how to call this, but basically so that the last segment of the URL was passed into `index.php` script that is in the `example.com/dir/`.

PS. My website is hosted on a shared web hosting platform.

Comment: This sounds more like a webserver configuration problem than PHP.

Comment: @Barmar: It's not a "problem," per se. I'm just trying to find out if I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having an index.php in every folder, you can leverage [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) by creating an .htaccess file and putting in the following:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Then, you can parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Oh, that's really cool. I need to try it, thanks. And I'm assuming that I will have to place that `.htaccess` into the `/home/dir/` folder, right?

Comment: It doesn't work the same way on every server, so I can't answer that with certainty. I suspect the answer is yes, though...

Comment: Actually adding an `.htaccess` to the `dir` directory itself with just `FallbackResource index.php` worked for me. (Notice no slash. Otherwise Apache was failing with error 500.) And then in `index.php` I was able to get the path from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I just learned something new today. So thanks again!